# session_regenerate_id(true) resets session variables

Tags: php, session

This is the code I use to initialize my sessions:

```
class session {
    public static function init() {
        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id(true);

        if (self::get('validSession') !== true) {            
            //start
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            session_start();
            self::set('validSession', true);
            //end
        }

    }

    public static function set($key, $value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($key) {
        if (isset($_SESSION[$key]))
            return $_SESSION[$key];
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is, the part between `//start` and `//end` gets called all the time, which leads to the old session being destroyed. When I remove `session_regenerate_id(true);`, everything seems to work fine except that the session id doesn't change (which is a big security hole)

Comment: You do realize that dropping ID *and* DATA is the very purpose of `session_regenerate_id(true)` ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php `"session_regenerate_id() will replace the current session id with a new one, and keep the current session information."`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php **`delete_old_session`** `Whether to delete the old associated session file or not.`

Comment: @mario that's for deleting the old session file *after* copying it to a file with the new session id, right?

Comment: It does not pertain to files by itself. The session file store is just one out of multiple storage backends. What the code actually does is `del_ses && PS(mod)->s_destroy(&PS(mod_data)` to kill off the session hash.

Comment: @mario but when I use `session_regenerate_id(false);` exactly the same happens as when I give the argument `true`

Comment: @mario I just tested this on a wamp server - and there `session_regenerate_id(false);` worked, but it won't work on my public server. Can this be because of some `php.ini` setting?

Answer (score 0):

Need close write session data `session_write_close()`, and start new session with regenerate SID

```
public static function init() {
    session_start();

    if (self::get('validSession') !== true) {            
        //start
        session_write_close();
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        self::set('validSession', true);
        //end
    }

}
```

Comment: `Warning: session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Trying to destroy uninitialized session` when the `if(){}` part is called. And won't placing `session_regenerate_id(true);` after `session_start` have no purpose, since `session_start` generates a new `id` anyways?

Comment: Try unset, destroy, close, start